Syncfusion MAUI Autocomplete numeric input
In my MAUI app i use the Syncfusion component SfAutocomplete. In the Xamarin version it used to support the property keyboard to turn the keyboard into a numerical keyboard. In the MAUI version however it doesn't seem to support this property. Is there a workaround for this?

In the Maui, you can use the Keyboard="Numeric" during you use the Entry. You can check this link about the Entry for more information.

Yes, that's correct, but I'm not using the Entry. I am using the Syncfusion component called SfAutocomplete, which internally uses an Entry component, but that's inaccessible from the outside, so I can't directly access that property.

I found the feature request about the new control AutoComplete API Design on Github. You can follow it up and provide the information. For further support with the Syncfusion component SfAutocomplete, please reach out to the Syncfusion developer team.
